# How to display a frame number on each frame of a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: variables, ffmpeg, frame

The test command I have is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh)-n: fontcolor=white: fontsize=40: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1: text=" -an -y out.mov
```

I want to display the frame number on each frame. However, setting the "text" variable to "n" does not help (it displays n) and %n seems to be the new line symbol. The thing that confuses me most is that this part

```
y=h-(2*lh)-n
```

works well, meaning it gets the right value of the current frame and moves the text up accordingly.

Comment: I believe this isn't currently possible with `ffmpeg`. I recommend adding a feature request to the [FFmpeg bug tracker](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/) (type: enhancement, priority: wish).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, could you recommend any other tool on Linux to achieve this particular purpose?

Comment: That was quick. FFmpeg development is quite active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this feature was not there in `ffmpeg`, but now it is. And this is how you do it:

```
...drawtext=text=%{n}:expansion=normal:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf:other_options...
```

Note that expansion should be set to normal, which is not the default now, but should be default in the future (according to the ffmpeg documentation).

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

You can use this command in the terminal or Powershell.
when you use this command with the f string in IDE so you can use this format

```
import os

cmd =f'''ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{{frame_num}}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy output.mp4'''

print(cmd)

os.system(cmd)
```